# Using {x: Bind} to bind to an XAML property, i.e. replacing {TemplateBinding XAMLProperty}

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, winui-3

It is stated [in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension) that

> Starting with Windows 10, version 1809, you can use the x:Bind markup extension anywhere you use TemplateBinding in a ControlTemplate.

However, when I try to replace **TemplateBinding** with **{x:Bind}** whilst defining the style of a custom control, as so,

```
<Style TargetType="local:PomodoroTimer" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PomodoroTimer">
                    <Grid Width="300" Height="300" Background="{x:Bind Background}">
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I get the following error: `Unable to resolve symbol 'Background'`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure **PomodoroTimer** has a ``Background`` to bind to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x:Bind` needs code-behind. (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#resource-dictionaries-with-x-bind:%7E:text=The%20%7Bx%3ABind%7D%20markup%20extension%20depends%20on%20code%20generation%2C%20so%20it%20needs%20a%20code%2Dbehind%20file%20containing%20a%20constructor%20that%20calls%20InitializeComponent%20(to%20initialize%20the%20generated%20code).))

So, thanks to **MainWindow.xaml.cs**, this works:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="Bindings.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:Bindings"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style
                x:Key="CustomButtonStyle"
                TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border
                                    BorderBrush="{x:Bind BorderBrush, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    BorderThickness="{x:Bind BorderThickness, Mode=OneWay}">
                                    <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button
            BorderBrush="SkyBlue"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Content="Custom Button"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For custom (templated) controls, I'd go with:

```xml
Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
```

or

```xml
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

for **TwoWay** bindings.

If you want to do `x:Bind` inside the `ControlTemplate`, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090708/2411960) might help.